# Symfony & mod_rewrite

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite

Looking for some good skills in mod_rewrite or Symfony (not sure from where the problem comes!)

I was using mod_rewrite normal, but somehow, I can't get this to work. I mean, when requesting this url:

A- http://www.balancextreme.es/pulseras-y-zapatillas-famosos.html

should load:

B- http://www.balancextreme.es/tiendaweb/pulseras-y-zapatillas-famosos/culture/es.html

ok, but not as a redirect, I mean, the address bar must be showing the url A.

Url B, for itself, charges perfectly, and so far this is my mod_rewrite line:

```
RewriteRule ^pulseras-y-zapatillas-famosos\.html$ /tiendaweb/pulseras-y-zapatillas-famosos/culture/es.html [L]
```

that doesn't work :(

Hope some can give some tips! thanks!

Comment: Did you add a `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: yes, it s there. but symfony still gives page not found. mm.. i was actually using a page as B url where with curl do the load keeping the A url in the address bar, but i lose the ip then for the cart so..

Comment: can you post the complete Apache Virtual host configuration section?

Comment: Please can you say me which located .htaccess file you have add Rule?

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony web directory have .htaccess file and you can add following code in first line. it's working for me. Hope this will solve your issue.

```
RewriteRule ^pulseras-y-zapatillas-famosos\.html$ /tiendaweb/pulseras-y-zapatillas-famosos/culture/es.html [L]
```